# Code after pipe is not executing in node js readstream

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, pipe, jsonstream

I have JSON as below
customers.json

```
   {
    "customers":[
          { "name": "customer1"},
          { "name": "customer2"},
          { "name": "customer3"}
         ]
   }

var fs = require('fs'),
    JSONStream = require('JSONStream'),
    es = require('event-stream');

async function run(){
    var getStream = function () {
        var jsonData = 'customers.json',
            stream = fs.createReadStream(jsonData, { encoding: 'utf8' }),
            parser = JSONStream.parse('customers.*');
        return stream.pipe(parser);
    };
    var arr = [];
    getStream()
        .on('data', function (chunk) {
            arr.push(chunk);
        })
        .on('end', function () {
            console.log('All the data in the file has been read' + arr.length);
        })
        .on('close', function (err) {
            console.log('Stream has been Closed');
        });

        console.log('end run()');
}

async function main(){
    run().then(function(){
        console.log('In then');
    }).catch(function(){
        console.log('In catch');
    })
}

main();
```

In output why "In then" printing before "end", "close". event.

How to get "In then" or In Catch after "end", "close" event.

How i can execute run() method in synchronous way.

Comment: JSONStream is primarily designed for huge files where you want to parse some sections of the file without having to parse the whole thing.  Is that the case here?  Or is my answer sufficient?

Comment: @LindaPaiste, Thats true i have huge json, so i cant read whole file in memory. So your answer is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

When running function asynchronously, calls to the `console` won't necessarily be made in order.  You should not rely on anything being done in order if it's async.

If you want to make `run()` synchronous, it's actually much much simpler than what you're doing now because you don't need to use streams at all.  You can just call `fs.readFileSync` to load the data from a local json file.  [This article](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-files-with-node-js/) explains some of the differences.

```
var fs = require('fs');

function run() {
  const rawData = fs.readFileSync("customers.json"); // Buffer
  const jsonData = JSON.parse(rawData); // object
  jsonData.customers.forEach( o => console.log(o.name) );
}

function main() {
  run();
  console.log("done");
}

main();
```

Console output:

```
customer1
customer2
customer3
done
```